# How do I include bibliography (.bbl file) in latex?

Tags: latex

I am trying to write my CV, and I want to include a list of publications. To do that, I want to include a .bbl file directly (which was generated using bibtex).
So, in my CV I do

\input{publications.bbl}

This seems to work fine, except for one thing: an asterisk (*) appears on the left to the lists of publications! I don't know where this * comes from and why it appears there. Any idea how I can remove this *?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The thebibliography environment is already included in .bbl files so processing the file with
`\input{publications.bbl}` should be enough.

The format of the publication list depends on the bibliography style used by BibTex with
the `\bibliographystyle` command. For more information about available styles take a look at:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Bibliography_styles

Answer (score 5):

Did you use `\nocite{*}`? putting `\nocite{*}` before `\bibliographystyle` can cause the asterisk to appear.

I had the same issue, this works for me:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{my_bib_file}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd have to see some code. but first you do

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}
   \input{publications.bbl}
\end{thebibliography}
```

Is that what you have? In fact, try this and see if you still get the "error":

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{ano05}
    A. Nonymous et al.\ 2005, \aap 123, 456\\[-20pt]
\bibitem{oe04}
    A.N. Other \& S.O.M. Ebody 2004, \pasp 123, 456\\[-20pt]
\end{thebibliography}
```